# python Scrapy get all text tags in a section

Tags: python, scrapy

I wanna use Scrapy to get any kind of text tag like h1,p,span ,strong and others  in side the section tag and ignore the others like img :

```
<section>
<h1>text</h1>
<h2>text</h2>

<span>text</span>

<img>text</img>

<p>text</p>
<p>text</p>
<p>text</p>
</section>
```

my starting code some thing like this:

```
import scrapy


class example (scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'example '
    allowed_domains = ['www.example .com']
    start_urls = ['example ']

    def parse(self, response):
      self.log('//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////')
      section= response.xpath('//section')
      for p in section.xpath('.//p/text()'):
          self.log('//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////')
          self.log(p.extract())
```

now as I said instead of only selecting p tags I need to  get any text tag . is there any way to do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case the only option - is to cycle through each html tag and filter it by it's name

```
def parse(self, response):
    req_tags = ['h1', 'p', 'span', 'strong']
    section_selector = response.css('section')
    for section in section_selector:
        texts = []
        for tag in section.css('*'):
            if tag.root.tag in req_tags:
                texts = texts + tag.css('*::text').getall()
        self.log(texts)
```

For this case - each tag name needs to be directly placed inside `req_tags`  list.